# Can't load library: /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries978435834650156898/OpenIMAJGrabber.so

Tags: java, linux

i'm working project for webcam scanning project in linux  ,, when i run program i found this type of exception:

**Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries978435834650156898/OpenIMAJGrabber.so**

while i have added this line
**System.load("/tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries978435834650156898/OpenIMAJGrabber.so");**

when i reach in /tmp folder there is no any OpenIMAJGrabber.so 
where is my OpenIMAJGrabber.so  in linux

Answer (score 0):

I would search for the OpenIMAJGrabber.so using locate:

```
$ locate OpenIMAJGrabber.so
```

If the locate db is not updated, you could try:

```
$ updatedb
```

And then repeat the command.

Best Reganrds, 
Ole Kristian Ek Hornnes

Comment: $ locate OpenIMAJGrabber.so , not working it gives : bash: locate: command not found

Comment: sudo apt-get install mlocate should install the 'locate' command